# sudo: unknown uid xxxxx: who are you?

Tags: sudo

I was using ssh and trying to upgrade a system from Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04. The connection had an issue so I had to login again to finish the upgrade. After running

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

that was required it seems that the system no longer recognizes me as a sudoer. If I run any command as sudo I'll get

```
sudo: unknown uid xxxxx: who are you?
```

(xxxxx is for the actual id of course) and similarly running `whoami` will return

```
whoami: cannot find name for user ID xxxxx
```

Also when I am trying to `ssh` I get a permission denied (despite the fact that I am still logged in in the machine on a different session).

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/passwd` and see if the ID is actually there.

Comment: @EeroAaltonen It's not... I'll ask if other people can login and let you know. It might be an issue with the open-ssl server because after the same upgrade to another system (and this time without any problems) I cannot ssh to the machine after the reboot required to complete the upgrade

Comment: I have restarted the putty and it worked for me. I am not sure if this will work or not but before going to any other solution just try that.

Answer (score 7):

This means that the current UID you are using is not present in `/etc/passwd`. This is not a serious issue if your system administration knows what he's doing. You can check it out using:

```
strace -f -F -o whoami whoami
```

Then now you have a file called `whoami`, parse it:

```
grep etc whoami
[...]
5029  open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had joined my computer to an Active Directory Domain, and `winbind` had crashed.

I fixed this with `systemctl restart winbind`.

Answer (score 0):

When `/etc` is accidentally moved / deleted, then you will also get this error.